# Constraints in optimization value

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, pyomo, glpk

I'm trying to optimize the following Mathematic model:

[image]

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

#dados entrada
T = [1,2,3] # Talhões
V = [1,2,3,4,5] #Veículos
t = len(T) # tamanho da variável de Talhões
v = len(V) # tamanho da variável de veículos
i = 0 #quer dizer usina
j = 0
c = [[0,4,3],[7,0,8],[2,9,0]]# Custo entre dois pontos i,j [ coleta ou recepção]
d = [56,47,60] # Número de fardos por talhão
D = 520 # capacidade do depósito da usina
C = [15,26,24]
w = 700 # peso por talhão
peso = 10000 # Peso por eixo isolado

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

model.x = pyo.Var(range(t),range(t),range(v), bounds=(0,1))
model.y = pyo.Var(range(t),range(v), bounds=(0,None))
#model.e = pyo.Var(range(t),range(v), bounds=(0,None))
x = model.x
y = model.y

#restricoes
model.talhao =      pyo.Constraint(expr = sum(y[(i,j)] for i in range(0,t) for j in range(0,v))==d[i])
model.caminhao =    pyo.Constraint(expr = sum(y[(i,j)] for i in range(0,t) for j in range(0,v)) <= C[j])
model.dependencia = pyo.Constraint(expr = y[(i,j)] <= sum(d[j]*x[(i,j,k)] for i in range(0,t) for j in range(0,t) for k in range(0,v)))
model.fluxo =       pyo.Constraint(expr = sum(x[(i,p,k)] for i in range(0,t) for p in range(0,t) for k in range(0,v))-sum(x[(p,j,k)] for p in range(0,t) for j in range(0,t) for k in range(0,v)) == 0)


#obj
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr = sum(c[i][j]*x[(i,j,k)] for i in range(0,t) for j in range(0,t) for k in range(0,v)))

opt = SolverFactory('glpk')
resultado = opt.solve(model)

model.pprint()

resultado.write()
#ABAIXO SÃO TENTATIVAS DE IMPRIMIR A FUNÇÃO OBJETIVO.
#print('Função Objetivo = ', model.obj())

#resultado = [pyo.value(x[(i,j,k)]) for i in range(0,t) for j in range(0,t) for k in range(0,v)]

#dados_ger['geracao'] = [pyo.value(Pg[g]) for g in dados_ger.id]
```

I don't know how make it work. When I try to print `x[(i,j,k)]`:

> ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object x[0,1,0]

I'm use for in one line, then I have doubt about the value.

On the `model.talhao` constraint when `i == 1`, `d[1]` too? Because for is in sum on left side of equality and I have the same question about other constraints.

Comment: As far as my experience with this `ValueError` can cover, this is generated either because you don't use any `initialize` argument when creating the `Var` and the `Var` is not constrained by any `Constraint` OR because the model was not solved to optimallity (`unbounded` or `infeasible`) and therefore, the model is not changed from initial state (With `Var` set as `None`).

Comment: Well, I found out that my problem was infeasible. I update my code in this link

https://github.com/hiroshi12345/Codes/blob/main/Optimization

but the objective function is returning zero. So I have no clue what to do right now. The problem looks like solved, but is not that right.

Comment: I don't think you're having the best approach for this problem. I'd drop using `ConstraintList`, and would use regular `Constraint` but indexed. Try to use `Set` to index `Var`, `Param` and `Constraint` and the formulation would be much more easy. I also, you need to provide `Var` with `domain` args (at least for `model.x`, since decision ar binary, not reals). I hope to have a little of time to try to help